# Is it against convention to expose a constructor function via dot notation?

Tags: javascript, function, constructor

Assume we have an IIFE that exposes a series of private functions via a dedicated namespace:

```
(function($){

  $.ConstructorFunction(){
    // ... builds stuff
  }

}(window.example = window.example || {} ))
```

Let's assume that the above is a little plugin, and I need to call that constructor outside of the IIFE. Which I do like this:

```
new example.ContructorFunction()
```

This seems like poor form and...ugly. On the one hand, I know that it's not good to have constructor functions in the global namespace so I'm keeping it private, but doing it this way seem contrary to every other way I've seen it done (without any dot notation).

Comment: If they're exposed, they're not private?!

Comment: "*This seems like poor form*" - no it's not. Why do you think so?

Comment: If you want to expose it on the global object instead of that `example` object, just pass `window` itself to your IIFE.

Comment: I'm still an amateur in Javascript but have been studying it for a while, have never seen a constructor being called via dot notation.

Comment: When the constructor is part of an object, you just access it as a property. Sure, usually a constructor function is just in scope directly, especially in modern JS with `import` statements, but there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Ok, that's all I needed to know. As long as I'm not going against best practice, I'm okay with the above.

Comment: Some WebAPIs Constructor are accessible through an object property e.g the [`Intl` Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) holds several constructors. And other WebAPIs are at least properties of the global object anyway.

Comment: @Modermo— "best" practice requires criteria so that alternatives can be evaluated. If your goal is to reduce global objects, there are strategies for that.

Comment: @Kaiido—re "*And they're all at least properties of the global object anyway*". That doesn't seem correct, e.g. *Intl.NumberFormat* is not available as *NumberFormat*. By giving the Intl object a leading capital, the convetion is broken with non-constructors like *Intl.getCanonicalLocales*.

Comment: @RobG by  **"at least"** I meant, if they're not props of deeper Objects, like in the case of `Intl`, they're *at least* props of the global Object (either some deeper object, either global) -> All WebAPIs are props of some object, be it the global one or some deeper one. Sorry that wasn't clear...